# Hibernate bytecode plugin causes exception

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, kotlin, gradle, bytecode

I added hibernate bytecode plugin to my spring boot project build file because it can solve many of my n+1 query problems. however when I run the project, it crashes. I googled about it and it was suggested to ensure that your compile and run java version be the same. I confirmed both of them is Java 17 so I don't think java versions mismatch. Spring boot version is 3.1.2 and Hibernate plugin version is the same as the one bundled with Spring boot.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate persister org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:103) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:75) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.processBootEntities(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:247) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.finishInitialization(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:185) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.initializeMappingModel(SessionFactoryImpl.java:320) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:270) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:431) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1455) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75) ~[spring-orm-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[spring-orm-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
... 20 common frames omitted 
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Operand stack overflow
Exception Details:
  Location:
web/scx/InternalTransaction$HibernateAccessOptimizer$Y79HCGnA.set_amount(Lweb/scx/autotradescx/database/models/payments/base/InternalTransaction;D)V @1: dload_1
  Reason:
Exceeded max stack size.
  Current Frame:
bci: @1
flags: { }
locals: { 'web/scx/InternalTransaction',double, double_2nd }
    stack: { 'web/scx/InternalTransaction' }
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 2a27 b500 12b1
```

It suggests the problem is my InternalTransaction entity which uses signle table inheritence. Here's the file:

```
@Entity
@Table(indexes = [Index(columnList = "user_id")])
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING, columnDefinition = "TEXT")
@DiscriminatorValue(NONE)
open class InternalTransaction(
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "internal_transaction_id_gen",  sequenceName = "internal_transaction_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "internal_transaction_id_gen")
open val id: Long = 0,
open var amount: Double,
open val description: String? = null,
open val date: Timestamp = Timestamp.from(Instant.now()),
open val account: String,
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
open val user: User
 ): Comparable<InternalTransaction> {
 override fun compareTo(other: InternalTransaction): Int {
    // Compare transactions by date first, then by amount if the dates are equal
    val dateComparison = date.compareTo(other.date)
    return if (dateComparison != 0) {
        dateComparison
    } else {
        amount.compareTo(other.amount)
    }
}


companion object {
    internal const val NONE = "none"
}

}
```

I dont see anything wrong here. And finally, the build.gradle.kts:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {

id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.1.2"
id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.2"

kotlin("jvm") version "1.8.22"
kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.8.22"
id("org.hibernate.orm") version "6.2.6.Final"
kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.8.22"

}

group = "web.scx"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
java.targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17


configurations {
compileOnly {
    extendsFrom(configurations.annotationProcessor.get())
}
}

hibernate {

enhancement {
    enableDirtyTracking
    enableLazyInitialization
    enableAssociationManagement
    enableExtendedEnhancement

}
}

repositories {
mavenCentral()
maven {url = uri("https://jitpack.io") }
}

dependencies {

implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.4")
implementation("org.postgresql:postgresql:42.5.1")
implementation("io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:3.0.0")
implementation("io.springfox:springfox-boot-starter:3.0.0")
implementation("io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:3.0.0")
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")
implementation("org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.5.3.Final")
implementation("com.github.gavlyukovskiy:p6spy-spring-boot-starter:1.9.0")
annotationProcessor("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor")
implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.10.0")
implementation("com.github.pengrad:java-telegram-bot-api:6.3.0")
implementation("com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.21.7")
implementation("io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.51.0")
implementation("org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.59")
implementation("org.apache.tuweni:tuweni-bytes:2.2.0")
implementation("org.apache.tuweni:tuweni-units:2.2.0")
implementation("com.auth0:java-jwt:4.2.1")
implementation("com.github.jhalterman:expiringmap:expiringmap-0.5.10")
implementation("com.github.alexdlaird:java-ngrok:1.6.1")
implementation("com.sun.mail:jakarta.mail:2.0.1")

implementation("com.google.api-client:google-api-client:2.0.1")
implementation("com.github.sidhant92:boolparser:1.0.9")
implementation("dev.samstevens.totp:totp-spring-boot-starter:1.7.1")
implementation("net.javacrumbs.shedlock:shedlock-spring:5.0.1")
implementation("net.javacrumbs.shedlock:shedlock-provider-jdbc-template:5.0.1")


}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
kotlinOptions {
    freeCompilerArgs += "-Xjsr305=strict"
    jvmTarget = "17"
}
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: You might have hit this bug: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-16772

Comment: @Codo Yes, Thank you. It was a platform bug. Can you please post the comment as an answer so I can mark this question as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception occurs because invalid byte code is being loaded. It likely is a bug of the plug-in or the underlying byte code generation library.

Possibly, you have run into this bug: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-16772